# iPhone 5 keeps on turning off even in DFU Mode

Tags: iphone, restore

I'm trying to restore my iPhone, since I've read that it could help me solve the continuous apple logo loop. But when I'm trying to restore it via DFU mode, it still shuts down and restarts. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the timing right.

Once the screen turns off, release both the power button after 0.5-1.0 seconds. Keep pressing the Home button, though.